# Legends in Chart.js, shows only one label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, chart.js, legend

Just a warning: I am new to chart.js!

I have a couple of horizontal bar charts and it works fine except one issue that I cannot shake off. I have 5 labels in y-axis but the legend on top of the graph only shows one small rectangle in the color of the first (topmost) bar and even that does not display the label itself, followed by list of labels. I thought it would display each label next to small bar same color as in chart.

Unfortunately, this is an intranet app and I cannot provide a link but here is what I have (data is passed to this function from an ajax call):

```
function drawRespChart(chartLabels, chartData) {
    var ctx = $("#rtChart");
    console.log("Labels Array: " + chartLabels);
    console.log("Data Array: " + chartData);

    if (chartRespTime)
        chartRespTime.destroy();

    var chart = {
        labels: chartLabels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: chartLabels,
                backgroundColor: ["#c45850", "#e8c3b9", "#3cba9f", "#8e5ea2", "#3e95cd"],
                data: chartData
            }
        ]
    };

    chartRespTime = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: chart,
        datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'start',
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'IDC Database Response Time (mili-seconds)'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Count'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        major: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fontColor: '#FF0000'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Response Time (ms)'
                    }
                }]
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    color: 'white',
                    display: function (context) {
                        return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 15;
                    },
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: Math.round
                }
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            responsive: true,
            showInlineValues: true,
            centeredInllineValues: true,
            tooltipCaretSize: 0
        }
    });
}
```

This is what I see in console window:

```
Labels Array: 0-350,350-700,700-1000,1000-1500
Data Array: 5065,32,27,3
```

What I see as legend is one rectangle, same color as first bar, followed by list of labels.

[image]

Comment: It does not work like that, if you want multiple labels, the property labels  can works like an array.  labels: ["0-350", "350-700", etc], it must be arranged it the way you want to show the y-axis.

Comment: Thank you. Are you referring to "label" in the "datasets" property section or Scales->yAxes under "Options"? Or is there a different section altogether called "Labels"?

Comment: my labels are in an array; in the "data" section I have "labels: chartLabels" which is an array. I just outlined the values to show what is in the array.

Comment: datasets: [{
                labels: chartLabels,
                backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"],
                data: chartData, 
            }]

I may be wrong but I remember watching a example where the label array must go inside the datasets.

Comment: I did the exact same thing but keep getting "chartLabels is undefined" error; oddly, it has no problem with chartData. It also uses values from chartLabels for y-axis labels, in the "Labels" property just above "datasets". Very strange. Not sure what to do next. I updated the post with this change.

Comment: I am getting a little closer. I updated the code in the post and the screen shot. I got rid of "undefined"; I am getting all labels displayed, just not next to each label's associated bar background color. Just one small rectangle followed by list of labels in the array.

Comment: That's weird, unless you are using an updated version than I. I found this, don't know if it is of any help, but here they are separating each datasets. https://jsfiddle.net/code4mk/1j62ey38/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they are using multiple data sets. It seems chart.js is incapable of displaying legends properly. I will remove legend for now and look for other open source chart libraries. I think Apex and C3 are good alternatives. Make one of your comments as answer and I will mark it. It is a shame they didn't think about implementing something fundamental.

Comment: Okay, good luck, will do. I have used chartist.js they are somehow similar, but they do accept an label array, I think that is in their configuration to show the labels at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that charts.js labels only works when you split the datasets.

Leaving an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/code4mk/1j62ey38/

```
datasets: [ {
          label: 'Result',
          fill:false,
          data: aDatasets1,
          backgroundColor: '#E91E63',
          },
         {
          label: 'Result2',
          fill:false,
          data: aDatasets2,
          backgroundColor: '#E91E93',
    }];
```